# How to programatically delete row from SwiftUI List and have the List view refreshes as well?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am looking to programatically delete a record from SwiftUI list datasource when I detect onAppear that list has a stale record which got updated when user was away from the List screen.

For example user was on Item Edit Screen. This screen marks a property in Environment object about which record is updated so that List screen can use this property to remove stale record from List data source when List reappears again. Hopefully this patterns of refreshing List is okay?

```
            List{
                Section{
                    Toggle(isOn: self.$showArchivedItems.onChange(showOptionsChanged)) {
                        Text("Show Archived Records).font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    ForEach(userData.items) { dataItem in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: dataItem)){
                            ListRowItemView(item: dataItem)
                        }
                    }.onDelete(perform: self.onDeletingItems)
                        .onAppear() {
                            if let updatedRecord = self.userData.lastUpdatedRecord {
                                if let updatedRecordId = self.userData.items.firstIndex(where: {return $0.id == updatedRecord.id}) {

                                    //OPTION #1 - Doesn’t work
                                    //self.userData.items.remove(at: updatedRecordId)
                                    //self.userData.items.append(updatedRecord)

                                    //OPTION #2 - Doesn’t work
                                    //self.userData.items.replaceSubrange(updatedRecordId... updatedRecordId, with: [updatedRecord])

                                    //OPTION #3 - works
                                        self.userData.items = self.storage.load()

                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

  private func onDeletingItems(indexset: IndexSet) {
    var itemsToDeactivate: [ItemModel] = []
    
    for index in indexset {
        userData.items[index].isArchived = true
        itemsToDeactivate.append(userData.items[index])
    }
    
    for item in itemsToDeactivate {
        storage.persist(dataItem: item)
    }
    
    userData.items.remove(atOffsets: indexset)
}
```

**Additional Code:**

**UserData.swift**

```
import Foundation
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [ItemModel]
    
    var lastUpdatedRecord: ItemModel? = nil
        
    init(data: [ItemModel] = []) {
        self.items = data
    }
    
    func clearLastUpdatedRecord() {
        self.lastUpdatedRecord = nil
    }
}
```

**List View**

```
struct ListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                List{ 
                    //ForEach on userData.items
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let storage = ItemLocalStorage()
        let userData = UserData(data: storage.load())
        let userSettings = SettingsModel()
        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(storage).environmentObject(userData).environmentObject(userSettings)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Issue is that I tried two options to specifically to just removed the stale record from List data source by finding its index (in OPTION #1) and appending updated instance OR in OPTION#2 I tried to replace the stale record with updated instance.

In both options the updated record do get added in list but stale record doesn't get removed from list, although stale records has updated data but I am seeing double instance of updated record.

When I entirely refresh the data source from storage (OPTION# 3) then list shows correct items i.e. only one instance of updated record.

Can anyone suggest how to programmatically remove a record from List data source in such a way that List also refreshes its View. I mean I don't have to load all records from storage again just to update list because of single record has updated. (In my app update is user trigged and only one record can be updated at a time, as per current design)

Also I am just wondering, the List do support editing items from List, like I implemented onDelete on List. Here the user can put List in editMode and delete single item. I am sure List is not invoking my storage to pull all data. So how List is managed to remove single item and refreshes its display as well?

Comment: Just remove element from `userData.items`

Comment: I have done so in OPTION#1 but it doesn’t remove from List display. List continue to display the item

Comment: Would you show code of `userData` type?

Comment: code for userData and some more around it added

Comment: Does your `ItemModel` type have an id field that is unique? Like a `UUID`?

Comment: Yes. The type ItemModel has Id of type UUID. In OPTION#1, I am using Id to find index of the record to delete it from list data source.

Comment: Thanks zrfrank. Any specific aspect you think I am not using correctly in List? The whole reason I had to handle the list refresh on ListView itself is because if I modifies the userData.Items on any other screen like ItemEditView screen then SwiftUI automatically make ItemEditView disappear and suddenly displays the ListView. I asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216941/in-swiftui-list-view-refresh-triggered-whenever-underlying-datasource-of-list-is. Also editing items of List datasource is not shown in Apple's landmark tutorial. Maybe I could have learned from there.

Comment: I guess, the problem comes from the `onAppear`. You may want to move it up/down the view hierarchy, also it is a good try to extract for example, the row into its own view. There also a potential cause that, the view's state update cycle, for example, the state is update in batch in a view update. I've met cases that my state update "stuck" between two update cycles, resulting in the view state "lacking behind".

Comment: @IshwarJindal I'm confused, why not just delete row directly in another scene?

Comment: @zrfrank - Deleting row is directly supported on List scene using the standard behaviour of List. I mean I have EditButton() in NavigationBar which when clicked put the list in Edit  mode and then user can delete by swiping the row. So there is no use case of deleting on another scene. The use case I am looking to achieve is where the each List row display the Name property from ItemModel. In another scene, user can edit the Name. When this happens then I want List row to reflect updated Name. If on the scene where use edited name I update the List data source then SwiftUI (1/2)

Comment: @zrfrank exit the scene on its own and presents List scene on screen which is wired. I mean just imagine you are on edit scene and you press "Save" button. The edit scene disappear automatically and user is taken back to List scene (2/2). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216941/in-swiftui-list-view-refresh-triggered-whenever-underlying-datasource-of-list-is

Comment: @IshwarJindal I think you are using SwiftUI in the imperative way, but swiftui has an Elm like architecture and the nature of reactive and declarative think about the web framework React. From what you’ve described, you are basically “fighting” the framework.

Comment: 1. It’s not weirded at all a view dismiss itself. Not even in UIKit. 2. You modify the data, the view bind to the data, when data change the view update itself that’s it. In your example, user edit the name, you update the model, then the view as long as you have bind the data to the view, the view will update, nothing else you need to implement. If you data model is struct, the you can simply use binding. if the row’s data model is an ObservableObject, then you need create an additional row view which observe that object. I do not see the point to manually update the list.

Comment: 3. Add row or delete row, are achieved by add/remove that element from your collection in your data model which been bind to the list/ForEach. The delete modifier on the ForEach is just a framework sugar for dynamicView in List to enable the built in behaviours, which at this stage a wrapper on top of UICollectionView. The actually Add/remove are achieved by modifying your data source. The “Action” is never an important concept in SwiftUI, only the “Data” matters.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround of the issue by capturing the datasource for List as an explicit state variable. If I now make changes to this state variable i.e. remove and add row then List display reflect the updated record.

Presumption is that SwiftUI likes @State more than anything else to automatically render the UI when underlying values changes. So instead of working on a copy of Array held in EnvironmentObject I passed the work to a dedicated @State variable. After this I am getting the desired behaviour.

My key changes are

**ListView.swift**

```
    @State private var items: [ItemModel] = []

    init(items: [ItemModel]) {
        _items = State(initialValue: items)
    }

    List{
                    Section{
                        Toggle(isOn: self.$showArchivedItems.onChange(showOptionsChanged)) {
                            Text("Show Archived”).font(.headline)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                        ForEach(self.items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: item)){
                                ListRowItemView(item: item)
                            }
                        }.onDelete(perform: self.onDeletingItems)
                            .onAppear() {
                                if let updatedRow = self.userData.lastUpdatedRecord {
                                    self.updateListDataSource(updatedRow)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())


    fileprivate func updateListDataSource(_ updatedRow: ItemModel) {
        if let updatedRecordId = self.items.firstIndex(where: {return $0.id == updatedRow.id}) {
            self.items.remove(at: updatedRecordId)
            self.items.append(updatedRow)
            self.userData.clearLastUpdatedRecord()
        }
    }

  private func onDeletingItems(indexset: IndexSet) {
        var itemsToDeactivate: [ItemModel] = []
        
        for index in indexset {
            userData.items[index].isArchived = true
            userData.items[index].lastModified = Date()
            itemsToDeactivate.append(userData.items[index])
        }
        
        for item in itemsToDeactivate {
            storage.persist(item: item)
            self.userData.items.removeAll { $0.id == item.id}
        }
        
        self.items.remove(atOffsets: indexset)
    }
```

**UserData.swift**

```
import Foundation
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [ItemModel]
    
     var lastUpdatedRecord: ItemModel? = nil {
        didSet {
            if let updatedInstance = lastUpdatedRecord {
                if let updatedInstanceIndex = self.items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == updatedInstance.id}) {
                    self.items.remove(at: updatedInstanceIndex)
                    self.items.append(updatedInstance)
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    init(data: [ItemModel] = []) {
        self.items = data
    }
    
    func clearLastUpdatedRecord() {
        self.lastUpdatedRecord = nil
    }
}
```